# `java.lang.ClassFormatError` list of error codes

Tags: java

Recently I got this error

```
Caught: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal field modifier in class **** : 0x3
java.lang.ClassFormatError : Illegal field modifiers in class **** : 0x3
```

I know the reason, I've been wondering - is there some table of those error codes and its explanation? Because I am curious what `0x3` means.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Field modifiers are bitwise ORs of the valid modifiers. Each of the valid modifiers (some of which are shown in @gustf's answer) are integers with single bits set.

As such, `0x3` would be the OR of two modifiers with numerical values `0x2` and `0x1`.

The `0x2` modifier means `ACC_PRIVATE`. The `0x1` modifier means `ACC_PUBLIC`.

This is a contradiction - you can't have something that is both public and private - so `0x3` is an invalid combination of modifiers.

This behaviour is described in [Section 4.5 of the JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.5):

> Fields of classes may set any of the flags in Table 4.4. However, a specific field of a class may have at most one of its ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_PROTECTED, and ACC_PUBLIC flags set ...

As such, setting `ACC_PRIVATE` and `ACC_PUBLIC` is explicitly forbidden by specification.

Comment: Oh I see. So that code is the result of `bitwise OR` operation. I get it. So basically JVM checks the OR result of field modifiers in order to check whether they are fine or not?

Comment: @user1432980 Yes. Added a reference to the JVM spec where it describes this.

Comment: So combining `private` and `protected` will lead to `0x5`?

Comment: @user1432980 That would be `(0x2 | 0x4) == 0x6`.

Comment: oh, my bad. I meant `public` and `protected`. I get it. Thanks!

Comment: but I wonder how it recognizes that `0x3` is the bad result and `a` (which is `private | static`) is good.

Comment: @user1432980 as a wild guess, I suspect it looks to see that "at most one of its ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_PROTECTED, and ACC_PUBLIC flags" is set, using bit masking.

Answer (score 4):

0x3 is an invalid modifier and has a contradictory meaning in this context.

A field can not have both `public` and `private` modifier at the same time.

The valid modifiers are

```
ACC_PUBLIC      0x0001
ACC_PRIVATE     0x0002
ACC_PROTECTED   0x0004
ACC_STATIC      0x0008
ACC_FINAL       0x0010
ACC_VOLATILE    0x0040
ACC_TRANSIENT   0x0080  
ACC_SYNTHETIC   0x1000
ACC_ENUM        0x4000
```

You can read more about them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.5-200-A.1)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of what `0x3` means.  The link commented by @Gendarme does.

Comment: @GrizzlyManBear not really. That just describes a bunch of numerically equal but unrelated error codes. It's unlikely that `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` has anything to do with class field modifiers.

Comment: @GrizzlyManBear: It because 0x3 is an illegal modifier, and the reason he gets a `ClassFormatError`. The link from @Gendarme just lists completely unrelated error codes.

Comment: So instead of correcting me, you should edit your question to better explain yourself.  As of right now the OP is asking about `0x3` and you have no mention of it at all in your answer.

Comment: Well it's indeed the error with modifiers as I generated `.class` with field `private public int` but I'd like to know what does `0x3` means.

Comment: @gustf it doesn't have *no* meaning, it has a contradictory meaning.

Comment: @gustf perhaps it'd be clearer why it is contradictory if you listed `ACC_PRIVATE = 0x0002` in the modifiers.

Comment: Erm...So in the end, why `0x3` is appeared at all? Or what are possible other `0xX` error messages?

Comment: @Andy Turner: True again, took the list/link from the wrong table first and forgot to change the list.